# Estou com um problema para pesquisar objetos dentro de objetos

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu faço o download de um arquivo JSON, por [exemplo](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/api.php?action=browsebysubject&subject=Atziri's%20Acuity&format=json), salvo e depois abro(isso tudo pelo javascript), e quero acessar a property 'Has_infobox_HTML', tentei usar o seguinte loop

```
var poeItem = new function() {
    this._getHTMLdata = function(fileData) {
        for (i = 0; i = fileData.query.data.length; i++); {
            if (fileData.query.data[i] && fileData.query.data[i].property == 'Has_infobox_HTML') {
                return fileData.query.data[i].dataitem[0].item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Porem ele não retorna nada, já tentei printar os 'i's e ele parece testar só para o 0 e depois para, já testei as outras partes do código e funcionam normalmente, o problema parece estar nessa parte em específico

Comment: o que vc quer retornar? toma cuidado que quando o `if` der `true` o `return` tá quebrando o `for`

Answer (score 0):

Haviam dois erros de sintaxe no seu script, coisa bem boba.

```
 for (i = 0; i =
```

O sinal de igual ali causa um loop infinito. Utilize o <.

```
for (i = 0; i < fileData.query.data.length; i++); {
```

E tem um ; após a declaração do loop.

Seu código corrigido:

```
 var poeItem = new function() {
     this._getHTMLdata = function(fileData) {
         for (var i = 0; i < fileData.query.data.length; i++) {
             if (fileData.query.data[i] && fileData.query.data[i].property == 'Has_infobox_HTML') {
                 return fileData.query.data[i].dataitem[0].item
             }
         }
     }
 }
```